# How do I find the difference between two numbers entered in text boxes?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I need to find the difference between two numbers from text boxes in visual basic. I need it to be able to find the difference between the numbers even if a larger number was entered into the second text box.

This what my code looks like now. Problem is that some numbers come out negative when they are not and other numbers come out fine.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim FirstNumber As Integer
    Dim SecondNumber As Integer
    Dim Difference As String

    FirstNumber = txtFirstNumber.Text
    SecondNumber = txtSecondNumber.Text
    Difference = txtDifferenceAnswer.Text

    If txtFirstNumber.Text < txtSecondNumber.Text Then

        Difference = txtSecondNumber.Text - txtFirstNumber.Text

    Else

        Difference = txtFirstNumber.Text - txtSecondNumber.Text

    End If

    txtDifferenceAnswer.Text = Difference
```

Comment: Strings are not Numbers even when they contains only digits. Set Option Strict On to your project and look at Int.MaxValue vs Long.MaxValue

Comment: _some numbers come out negative when they are not_ Which numbers? Give us everything you know about the inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the absolute value and you should use `Int32.TryParse`:

```
Dim FirstNumber As Int32
Dim SecondNumber As Int32
Dim Difference As Int32

If Int32.TryParse(txtFirstNumber.Text, FirstNumber) AndAlso Int32.TryParse(txtSecondNumber.Text, FirstNumber) Then
    Difference = Math.Abs(FirstNumber - SecondNumber)
    txtDifferenceAnswer.Text = Difference.ToString()
Else
    txtDifferenceAnswer.Text = "Enter valid integers!"
EndIf
```

I recommend to set [`Option Strict` to `On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) in your settings. Then your code would not compile which is a good thing since you learn quickly how to write robust and efficient code that doesn't rely on compiler tricks to parse your incompatible types.